# Why is openssl_decrypt adding escape slashes to the outputted data?

Tags: php

I'm using openssl_encrypt to encrypt some JSON data before inserting it into an SQL DB.

```
$cypherMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
$key = 'WHATEVER';

// Then we generate a random Initialization Vector - which is stored with record in DB

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cypherMethod));

// Now we run the encryption process and convert output to Base64 to make DB storage easier

$userdata = openssl_encrypt($userdata, $cypherMethod, $key, $options=0, $iv);
$userdata = base64_encode($userdata);
```

This works fine, and the data is then added to the DB.

Then on the other end when I decrypt:

```
$cypherMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
$key = 'WHATEVER';
$iv = 'GRABBED FROM DB RECORD';

$userdata = base64_decode($userdata);
$userdata = openssl_decrypt($userdata, $cypherMethod, $key, $options=0, $iv);
```

Now, the decryption process works fine, but by JSON data ends up with escape slashes, which I then have to remove with stripslashes().

It's not a huge issue, but why are the slashes appearing? I know that Base64 adds slashes, but I'm only base64 encoding after the initial encryption, so I can't understand how the slashes make it into the underlying JSON data?

Comment: _“I know that Base64 adds slashes”_ - no, it does not “add slashes” in general; the slash is one of the characters of the base64 _alphabet_, so it might occur in arbitrary places in the base64 encoded data. But that has nothing whatsoever to do with any slashes in your decoded JSON data. The slashes that might be contained in the base64 decoded data, will be gone again, when you base64 _decode_ that data again. The slashes in your JSON must have been in there before you did the base64 en-/decoding already.

Comment: And they must have been in there before the openssl en- and decryption as well, because that does not actually _falsify_ data either.

Comment: Likely you messed up your data, by doing some SQL escaping to make it safe for insertion in to the database, _before_ the process you have shown us above takes place. That would obviously be the completely wrong point to do that.

Comment: I'll have another look. Thanks for confirming this is nothing to do with openssl though.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @CBroe should direct you into the right place to search for. Below you find your code append with some JSON data to prove that OpenSSL does not change the data during encryption or decryption.

The output will be:

```
userdata before encryption: {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}
userdata after encryption:  {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}
```

**Security warning**: Your code uses a hard coded encryption key that is for demonstration only, do not use this in production:

```
<?php
$cypherMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
$key = 'WHATEVER'; // ### Security warning: don't use a hard coded key in production

$userdata = '{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}';
echo 'userdata before encryption: ' . $userdata . PHP_EOL;
// Then we generate a random Initialization Vector - which is stored with record in DB
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cypherMethod));
// Now we run the encryption process and convert output to Base64 to make DB storage easier
$userdata = openssl_encrypt($userdata, $cypherMethod, $key, $options=0, $iv);
$userdata = base64_encode($userdata);

//$cypherMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
//$key = 'WHATEVER';
//$iv = 'GRABBED FROM DB RECORD';

$userdataDec = base64_decode($userdata);
$userdataDec = openssl_decrypt($userdataDec, $cypherMethod, $key, $options=0, $iv);
echo 'userdata after encryption:  ' . $userdataDec . PHP_EOL;
?>
```